# CSS styling for wordpress template

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a custom page template for wordpress and can't figure out how to remove the background color/removing padding for the section.

I'm working on a real estate site and have the wp-listings plugin installed. The archive page looks like this: http://placerhomes.net/listings

With this page the content is not restricted horizontally and the white background of a typical page is removed.

I'm trying to create a page template that's identical to this so that I can use the shortcodes for some more flexibility. Currently when using the shortcodes the page looks like this: http://placerhomes.net/shortcode

You'll notice there is a white background and the content doesn't span the whole horizontal length of the section.

From what I can see (I'm a noob) it looks like the section I'm trying to change is called main.content.

I can't seem to find that section in my css files. Can anyone help me figure out what I need to do to remove the white background and make the content span the full width of the div?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the padding and background-image using this CSS code. Make sure you are using this in a custom file or below the already present code to overwrite the current CSS.

```
.content .entry {
  background-color: transparent;   
}

.entry {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If below css is not rendering to other page you need to update plugin css in,

plugin/wp-listing/include/css/wp-listing.css

where you need to comment below code

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
border-color: -moz-use-text-color #efefef #efefef;
border-image: none;
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
border-style: none solid solid;
border-width: medium 1px 1px;
color: #999;
```

Or you can duplicate class and use only those css which you want in your page if you can.

P tag with class name 'listing-address', 
there is br tag between span tag. Remove it.

you need to duplicate new class entry in which you have to hide

```
background-color: #fff;
```

and adjust or remove padding in same class to set your requirement.

Comment: Try to create duplicate class because there are few class like content, entry which are rendering on each page with word press loop so if you edit core css class, it might effect on other page as well.